# Tweets of twitter by email address and password

Tags: c#, vb.net, twitter

I am using following code to get tweets by Handle name

```
authtoken = "2325327612-123456"
tokensecret = "abcdedff"
objTwitter = New TwitterVB2.TwitterOAuth("123abvc", "567aaaa", authtoken, tokensecret)
strJson = objTwitter.OAuthWebRequest(OAuth.Method.GET, "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=" & twitterHandle & "&count=300", "")
```

Is it possible to get tweets from Email address and password we use for login the account. If yes how can I get tweets if I know the username and password of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Accessing the Twitter API with a users's username/email address and password was called "Basic Auth" and it was phased out in 2010.  In order to access Twitter data as a particular user, that user has to authorize your application via OAuth.

I would start reading here: [Twitter Developers OAuth FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq)